# How using preg_replace overall on a arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two questions, first

```
<?php
$text = "a iKo SaioT eeee";
$fonts = "a|i|u|e|o";
$newText = preg_replace("#([$fonts].+?(?=[^$fonts![:space:]]))#us", '<b>$1</b>', $text);
echo $newText;
?>
```

Will be like (**a** **i**K**o** S**aio**T eeee). Not (**a** **i**K**o** S**aio**T **eeee**). Why the last `eeee` letter does not change bold? And when `$text = "a"` The result does not turn into bold too

Second, how to convert this code into jquery

`$newText = preg_replace("#([$fonts].+?(?=[^$fonts![:space:]]))#us", '<b>$1</b>', $text);`

Cause `$fonts` is arrays not same in php

Comment: Did you tryied adding `+` to `#([$fonts]----->+<-----.+?` ?

Comment: Because I added an exception `[^$fonts![:space:]]`

Comment: The regular expression has several issues, but more importantly, it is not clear from your question by which logic you want to apply bold. With `.+` you seem to want to allow non-vowels to also be included in the bold tags, but it is not clear when you want this too happen.

Comment: Oh i need without `space` too. Because if I put `space` in array `a|i|u|e|o|[:space:]`. It will be like this `<b>e</b><b>e</b><b>e</b><b>e</b>` will be separate. And if i using `#([$fonts]?(?=[^$fonts![:space:]]))#us` without `.+`, first and last, fonts not being bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below javascript snippet, you'll notice it takes the text from the DIV.

Then the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) pattern is constructed based on the fonts variable.

And when that pattern is used in the replace, it puts a bold tag around all the groups of lowercase letters.

Then the text in the div gets replaced with that.

```js
var element = $('#test span:first');
let oldText = element.text();    

let fonts = "aiueo";
let pattern = new RegExp('(['+ fonts +']+)','g');

let newText = oldText.replace(pattern, '<b>$1</b>');

element.replaceWith(newText);

console.log("pattern: "+ pattern);
console.log("oldText: "+ oldText);
console.log("newText: "+ newText);

var arabictest=" test\n لَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ  تَشَهَّدْ \n test";
console.log(arabictest.replace(/([\u0600-\u06FF]+(?:\s+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)*)/g, '<b>$1</b>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"><span>a iKo SaioT eeee</span></div>
```

Note that no pipes are used in the pattern.
Because in a character class `[a|b]` a pipe is just another character, not a regex OR like in `(a|b)`.

As for the PHP.
The regex syntax in javascript (orginally inspired by Perl 4) is much more limited compared to the syntax used in PHP (which uses the PCRE regex engine).
So one can assume that about any regex pattern written for javascript will also work for PHP.

Examples:

```
<?php
$text = "a iKo SaioT eeee";
$fonts = "aiueo";
$pattern = "/([$fonts]+)/";
$newText = preg_replace($pattern, "<b>$1</b>", $text);
echo $newText;
echo "<br/><br/>";

$text2 = "fie faa fuu foo bar foobar";
$words = "foo|bar";
echo preg_replace("/$words/", "<b>$0</b>", $text2);
echo "<br/>";
echo preg_replace("/\b($words)\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $text2);

$arabictext = "test <br/> لَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ  تَشَهَّدْ  <br/> test";
echo preg_replace("%([\u{0600}-\u{06FF}]+(?:\s+[\u{0600}-\u{06FF}]+)*)%u", "<b>$1</b>", $arabictext);
```

Comment: Oh you answer second question? Emm open this https://jsfiddle.net/yz8bf3us/ and please click right and inspect in font arabic (insert text in textarea, will show text arabic). You will find this `<p><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>فَإِذَا</b></b> ...... ` bla bla bla. Can you make to be like this `<b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ </b>`

Comment: Or change question how make this in jquery.  Select all font arab `$arabic[i]` EXEPTION space in font arab... If in php like this `'#([$arabic].+?(?=[^$arabic![:space:]))#us';`

Comment: fiddled a bit with the pattern for arabictest, now it doesn't remove the whitespaces before the bolded text.

Comment: @user3547311 I added a tad op PHP to the answer. Hadn't done that before because regex for javascript is only a minimal set compared to the PCRE regex engine. For example, go to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and compare the quick reference tab between the javascript and pcre flavors to get the point.

Comment: do you have email?

Comment: @user3547311 Sure, but don't plan to share that. Why?

Comment: So, I want to ask in person. Open this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291338/how-to-separate-paragraphs-between-alphabetical-and-arabic-fonts?noredirect=1#comment77545115_45291338)
Some are missing, and this is probably the last of the problem